# Prove that there exist $n$ consecutive positive integers with the $i$th integer divisible by the $i$th prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, chinese-remainder-theorem

Prove that for any positive integer $n$, there exist $n$ consecutive positive integers $a_1, a_2,...,a_n$ such that $p_i |a_i $ for each $i$, where $p_i$ denotes the $i$th prime?

Having a lot of trouble with this problem, I tried searching this question up  but only got problems similar to it and it still didn't quite help. We are currently covering a section on The Chinese Remainder Theorem. Our teacher showed us two ways of utilizing this theorem, one via back-substitution and one via the classical approach. Looking through my notes I don't see anything resembling this problem, any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem:

Consider solutions to
$$ \begin{align}
x &\equiv 0 \pmod 2 \\
x+1 &\equiv 0 \pmod 3 \\
x+2 &\equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
\cdots \\
x+n &\equiv 0 \pmod {p_{n+1}}.
\end{align}$$

Then the Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees your solution, which is exactly a collection of $(n+1)$ consecutive integers $x, x + 1, x + 2, \ldots, x+n$ with the desired divisibility conditions.

Comment: I'm still not quite seeing what you mean, how did you get those solutions, I'm not sure how it guarantees the given solution?

Comment: The moduli are relatively prime, so the Chinese remainder theorem guarantees that there is an $x$ that is a simultaneous solution. Then $x, x+1, x+2, \ldots$ is your collection of consecutive integers.